# Rattling noise from passenger side Air Vent

Tags: jeep, vents

My wife has a 2008 Jeep Liberty.  Recently when the air is on (vent, heat or AC) a rattling noise that I would say sounds similar to...fan bearings is coming from the passenger side dash air vent.

Not sure what the issue is, the sound does not seem to come from any of the other vents.

Any suggestions on what the issue is?  Is this something I can get into and fix?

Comment: What is the sound exactly? Does it happen with just the fan on but without a/c or heat? Does it happen with the heat on?

Comment: As mentioned if the vents are blowing anything the vent is making the noise.  So if the dial for the vent is on the noise is there, it does not seem to get noticeably louder if you turn the vents up to full blast however.  I am not sure how to describe the noise beyond a rattle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main possibilities that are on my mind for what your problem is:

1) The blower motor is going bad and just needs replacing. I'm not sure where the access to the blower motor is on your vehicle, but generally this is a fairly easy repair to do.

2) The blend door in the HVAC enclosure is sticking or the motor is being overdriven, producing a repeated "clacking" noise. This can often be remedied by turning the temperature control all the way to hot, waiting a few seconds for the sound to stop, and then turning the temperature back down to the desired cooling. Another possibility is to pull the fuse for this circuit, turn the ignition to on, wait a couple minutes, turn the ignition off, replace the fuse, and turn the ignition on. This may reset the circuit memory and fix the issue.

3) Animals. The blower motor housing on cars is a common refuge for rodent folk. You can usually tell if they've taken up living there from the smell though.

I would try the blend door first and if the sound doesn't go away from adjusting the temp to max on both ends of the spectrum, pull the blower motor and see if anything got inside the housing, or if the motor is going bad.

Comment: Ill give #2 a try when I get home this evening, thanks.

Comment: Turned out to be #1.  The blower motor sits under/behind the glove box.  It is quite easy to take out and replace...well it will be once the part comes in this week anyway.  Best guess is the bearings are shot.